# How do I remove the revision information from a node edit form?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I'm hoping someone can help a Drupal beginner removing a view from my page. The purpose of it is a for data collection.

This is the section I am trying to remove:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Image link is broken.

Answer (score 10):

In your `MODULE_form_alter` hook add:

```
$form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 4):

The best solution would be to **bind it to a permission** which can then be tied to a role.

use this code in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['revision_information']['#access'] = user_access('view revisions');
}
```

Then only roles with 'view revisions' permission can see this tab.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Jammer](http://drupal.org/project/jammer).

The best description for what that module does can be found in the project page:

> This module is intended to be a
>   dumping ground for removing things
>   from the user interface that might not
>   be appropriate in all cases or just
>   plain confuses certain audiences.

The revision information that you mentioned is one of the many things that are considered "confusing" and that you can remove with jammer.

P.S: An extra plus is that Jammer has a stable D7 version.

Answer (score 1):

This can done by using following code in hook_form_alter function.

```
$form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE; 
          OR
$form['revision_information']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also use :

```
$form['revision_information']['#type'] = 'hidden';
```